# Obtener valor de campo dentro de setting/general

Tags: wordpress

He agregado un campo personalizado a los ajustes > generales de wordpress, el campo lo agregue mediante el metodo add_settings_field(), en este campo pretendo poner el tipo de cambio del dia, hasta aqui todo muy bien el campo existe y se guarda la información.

La duda que tengo es como puedo obtener el valor de este campo dentro de mi plantilla o tema?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/)?

Comment: Gracias me funcino! get_option('nombre_del_campo');